# R Studio Homework Help, looking at replication of coin tosses

Tags: r

2. In this exercise, you will use 2500 replications to study the distribution of the longest run of heads in 100 tosses. Let Xi represent the length of the longest run of heads in the ith replication.
   (a) Create an 100 by 2500 matrix of independent tosses of a fair coin. The 2500 columns of this matrix represent independent replications of the experiment of tossing a fair coin 100 times. You may represent heads and tails with “H” and “T”, or with 0 and 1, or with any other sensible choices.
   (b) Let μ represent the mean length of the longest run of heads in 100 tosses of a fair coin. Let X ̄ be the sample mean of the 2500 Xi values. As discussed is class, μ can be unbiasedly estimated by X ̄. Use the n simulations from part (a) to compute X ̄, and construct a 95% confidence interval for μ.

In here, I solved part A with no problem. Part B I am running into an issue with dim(x) needing to be a positive value.

```
longest_runs <- apply(toss, 2, function(replication) {
  runs <- rle(replication)
  max_heads_run <- max(runs$lengths[runs$values == "H"], default = 0)
  return(max_heads_run)
})
```

toss is an assigned value equal to 100. I also have the matrix of 2500 observations, but when I use that a 1 by 4 matrix of just 0's.

Comment: When you say "toss is an assigned value equal to 100" do you mean this call is basically `apply(100, 2, function ...` )? `apply()` expects a matrix or data.frame - you can pass it your 100x2500 matrix directly and it will work from that, but you say you've not had any luck trying that approach.

Comment: Can you provide a few rows/columns of your data frame to test?  I suggest transposing it (so it's 2500 rows x 100 columns) and providing the top few rows by using `dput(head(t(mydata)))`.